# How to Pass Workflow Propert in Control-Parm to FTL File in Alfresco?

Tags: java, html, xml, alfresco, freemarker

So for my project, we have some javascript code running as a rule within the Alfresco repository. So whenever a new document comes into a certain space, a new folder is dynamically created and that document is moved into that newly created space.  Additionally, whenever a new folder is created, a property is updated like so for the document (expect caseID is actually a dynamically generated value based on a sequence in our database):

```
//Add caseID as a property of the folder
var props = new Array(1);
props["wf:caseIDNum"] = caseID;
var newAspect = newNewSpaceName.addAspect("wf:caseID",props);
```

However, now we want to be able to reference that newly created aspect/property during the course of our workflow in our share-workflow-form-config-.xml file so that it can be passed as a parameter to our control template. That is, currently we have:

```
<field id="wf:submitCode" label-id="workflow.field.outcome" set="actions">
                  <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/workflow/custom-activiti-transitions.ftl"/>
               </field>
```

But what we want is something like the below:

```
<field id="wf:submitCode" label-id="workflow.field.outcome" set="actions">
                  <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/workflow/custom-activiti-transitions.ftl">
                     <control-param name="caseID">wf:caseIDNum</control-param>
                  </control>
               </field>
```

So my question is, is that the proper syntax to pass a variable/property from the workflow model to the FTL file via the control param?

**Edit (10/25/12)** -

So based on the help given here, I tried to modify my ftl page like so...

**custom-activiti-transitions.ftl**:

```
<#assign caseID = "">
<#if field.control.params.caseID??>
    <#assign caseID = field.control.params.caseID>
<#else>
    <#assign caseID = null>
</#if>

<style type="text/css">

.button {
border: 1px solid #666;
background: #DCDCDC;
padding: 5px;
color: #333;
text-shadow: 1px 1px #fff;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px
border-radius: 5px;
cursor: pointer;
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
a.button:hover {
background: #bbb;
color: #000;
text-shadow: 1px 1px #eee;
}

a.button:active {
position: relative;
top: 1px;
left: 1px;
-moz-box-shadow: none;
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
box-shadow: none;
}

</style>

<a class="button" href="#" onClick="MyWindow=window.open('http://localhost:8080/alfresco/faces/jsp/custom/CodeSelector.jsp?caseID=${caseID}','My Window','toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=600,height=300'); return false;" style="text-decoration:none" target="_blank"><span>Add Codes</span></a>
```

And in my **share-workflow-form-config.xml**, I changed any instance of:

```
<field id="wf:submitCode" label-id="workflow.field.outcome" set="actions">
 <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/workflow/custom-activiti-transitions.ftl">
 </control>
</field>
```

to...

```
<field id="wf:submitCode" label-id="workflow.field.outcome" set="actions">
 <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/workflow/custom-activiti-transitions.ftl">
  <control-param name="caseID">wf:caseIDNum</control-param>
 </control>
</field>
```

My problem is that in the **share-workflow-form-config.xml** where I specify the `control-param`, I can get it to pass in a hard coded value like "30". However, when I try to get the value of the workflow property like `wf:caseIDNum`, it returns the actual string in the parameter like:

`http://localhost:8080/alfresco/faces/jsp/custom/CodeSelector.jsp?caseID=wfcaseIDNum`

as opposed to the actual value for the property, i.e. "30".

Any ideas on what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's exactly as skuro said and you're not doing this rightly.

Very simple your config is correct but your ftl lacks some logic.

Why will you first check on `<#if field.control.params.caseID??>`
And then not assign it?

It should be:

```
<#if field.control.params.caseID??>
   <#assign caseID = field.control.params.caseID>
<#else>
   <#assign caseID = 1>
</#if>
```

There is no need of a context or args or something.

Take a look at the default ones like `/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/textarea.ftl`

----- UPDATE -----

So how can one access another field in this template.
So we've got another field "wf:caseIDNum" and we want to access that one.

You could use the following hacky mechanism to get it

```
${form.fields["prop_" + caseID?replace(":","_")].value}
```

in the form.fields all the current form properties are stored.

BTW don't forget to show the "wf:caseIDNum" and the hidden.ftl template or else the property won't be populated in the fields object ;).

Comment: Ah, yeah. Idk why I was over thinking that. I was working with someone else's code originally and thought that everything was correct in their logic. But that seems to work now in terms of properly passing in the hard coded value from the control parameter in **share-workflow-form-config.xml**. However, when I now try to change the "30" in the control parameter to wf:caseIDNum, it seems to pass in the actual string "wf:caseIDNum" instead of the value associated with that property. Do you know how I might fix that?

Comment: But what do you do with the "wf:submitCode" value? if nothing then why not generating this field on the "wf:caseIDNum" ?

Comment: Again, this is working with some previous code. But I believe the "wf:submitCode" is just a submit button. But what do you mean "why not generating this field on the 'wf:caseIDNum'"? What would that do?

Comment: That you can generate the template on that specific field:<field id="wf:caseIDNum" label-id="workflow.field.outcome" set="actions">
 <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/workflow/custom-activiti-transitions.ftl">
  <control-param name="caseID">wf:caseIDNum</control-param>
 </control>
</field>

and use ${field.value}

Comment: Okay, so a few questions. I changed the instances of `<field id="wf:submitCode">` to `<field id="wf:caseIDNum">`. And I added '<show id="wf:caseIDNum"/>` in addition to wherever there was a `<show id=wf:submitCode"/>`. However, where should I use this `${field.value}`? And where is this `${form.fields["prop_" + caseID?replace(":","_")].value}` being used? In the ftl file? And what do you mean show the hidden.ftl file?

Comment: If you use caseIDNum, then just use ${field.value} and leave the rest. Use it where ever you like to show the value. Like in your current code assign it to caseID.

Comment: So again, I changed the `field id` values to `wf:caseIDNum`, and I added that `<show id="wf:caseIDNum"/>` and in my control param I did `<control-param name="caseID">${field.value}</control-param>` but it still outputs the url `http://localhost:8080/alfresco/faces/jsp/custom/CodeSelector.jsp?caseID=${field.value}` Is there something I am missing?

Comment: I think you need proper share training.....  put in your ftl <#assign caseID = field.value> or you should consider hiring an expert

Comment: Ah sorry. I ended up trying that before you responded. That just returns a blank. I tried changing the field id to to another property and using `caseID = field.value` in my ftl and that works, as in it returns the value of that property. So that's why I'm wondering if I need to do something else to make that wf:caseIDNum value visible, outside of what I already modified? i.e. with the hidden.ftl you mentioned before?

Comment: I think your caseID property is just blank, so it doesn't, contains a value.

Comment: That's the thing though. When I look in my workfow console at my process instance, I see that the `wf_caseIDNum` is indeed set to a value of "31"...so I'm not sure why it's returning blank? :/

Comment: Just wanted to update this. I finally ended up figuring out what was wrong, which turned out to be a number of things. I had to add a step to pass the actual property of the folder from the javascript to the workflow parameters, had to add in an actual workflow property (different from the previous folder aspect/property I had added), and I had to use that field.value in my ftl file. Bit messy, but good enough for my needs. Thanks for all your help! :)

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on how you implement the control template. The aspect, and its related property are a static entity, they don't get "created" on the folder, they get "applied" to it. On a side note, please be aware that aspects are NOT automatically inherited by children nodes of a folder.

That said, you can indeed specify `wf:caseID` as the `caseID` input parameter of the template, than within the FTL you can refer to such a property with

```
field.control.params.caseID
```

You will need to implement the logic to go and retrieve the provided property and render it on screen properly.