# Integrate applet on workflow Alfresco

Tags: workflow, alfresco, activiti, alfresco-share, workflow-activity

**Question:** I have an applet that makes "changes" on PDFs, and after this I have to save the changes to the respective file on the respository. How can I integrate this applet on a workflow? Any hint or document to read?

I thought in a task form (in a task-edit page), with a new component with a button to call the applet, but this is a good idea? And works? Because I wanted when the person press the accept button, the applet is called, and only then when the change was made, the task would be completed. But how?

Comment: You need to use a service task instead of applets

Comment: But I have to integrate a applet, I can't modificate this :S 
I want to call the applet on the accept button of the task or something on the task form (task-edit?). 
There must be a way to integrate right?

Comment: There is, but it isn't pretty !

Comment: But I can not transform the applet :( Any advice to make the integration with applet?

Comment: @YounesRegaieg can you help me?

Comment: You should not try to submit. The task will be closed by the behaviour. Have you written the behavior already ? I think it would be better to start from there.

Comment: i'm starting with this. But if i shoud not try to submit, how to put "task done" @MarcoAltieri?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not have the details of your applet and so I cannot be sure that it is possible, but you can try to simply use some javascript to access public methods of your applet.

The form-engine in Alfresco is easily customisable writing your custom controls.
The custom control will generate the html and the javascript necessary to embed your applet in the form and call it when a button is pressed.

It would be useful to know if you can intercept on Alfresco the update executed by the applet. For example, you can have a listener (behaviour) in Alfresco that will be called when the document is updated. If, based on your business logic, the listener can understand that the applet has completed the operation, it can automatically fire the transition of the workflow.
This solution is robust because the update executed by the applet and the update of the task will be transactional: they both succeed or the update is rolled back.

If possible, **do not call the applet and the transition of the workflow separately**: the two operations won't be atomic and you can end up with an inconsistent repository.

**Update**
To avoid any customisation of Alfresco functionality, do not modify the acitiviti transitions. Given that you only need to add a button to call your applet, use a custom ftl and specify it in the configuration of your form.

The following article is a good guide to learn how to do it (I strongly suggest to read it and follow the exercise):

[Jeff Potts' article on Advanced Workflows](http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/workflow/tutorial/tutorial.html#step-3-configure-alfresco-share)

As you can see at paragraph [Edit share-config-custom.xml](http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/workflow/tutorial/tutorial.html#step-3-configure-alfresco-share), you can specify the free marker template for rendering each field in your form. You can specify, if you prefer, a different template to use for your transition button. This template will render the applet and the html and javascript to call it.

The following class is an example (it is a snippet copied from real code, I have not tested it, it is meant only to show the main part of a behaviour) of a behaviour that listens for the creation of a node or the update of its properties. You have to choose what it is better for you. What exactly does the applet? Does it create a new node? Or update its properties ? Or update the content of the node?

The following link gives you an example of code that triggers the transition:
[Trigger Activiti workflow for task sitting in ReceiveTask looping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15640480/trigger-activiti-workflow-for-task-sitting-in-receivetask-looping)

```
package com.someco.alfresco.behaviours;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.alfresco.repo.node.NodeServicePolicies.OnCreateNodePolicy;
import org.alfresco.repo.node.NodeServicePolicies.OnUpdatePropertiesPolicy;
import org.alfresco.repo.policy.Behaviour;
import org.alfresco.repo.policy.JavaBehaviour;
import org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.ChildAssociationRef;
import org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.NodeRef;
import org.alfresco.service.cmr.site.SiteInfo;
import org.alfresco.service.namespace.NamespaceService;
import org.alfresco.service.namespace.QName;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;


public class SomeObjectCreatePolicy implements OnCreateNodePolicy, OnUpdatePropertiesPolicy {
    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SomeObjectCreatePolicy.class);

    @Override
    public void init() {
        this.policyComponent.bindClassBehaviour(
                QName.createQName(NamespaceService.ALFRESCO_URI, "onCreateNode"),
                Model.TYPE_ENTITY_OBJECT,
                new JavaBehaviour(this, "onCreateNode", 
                        Behaviour.NotificationFrequency.TRANSACTION_COMMIT));

        this.policyComponent.bindClassBehaviour(
                QName.createQName(NamespaceService.ALFRESCO_URI, "onUpdateProperties"),
                Model.TYPE_ENTITY_OBJECT,
                new JavaBehaviour(this, "onUpdateProperties", 
                        Behaviour.NotificationFrequency.EVERY_EVENT));
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateNode(ChildAssociationRef childAssocRef) {
        /* Your logic to fire the transition */
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdateProperties(NodeRef nodeRef,
            Map<QName, Serializable> before, Map<QName, Serializable> after) {
        /* Your logic to fire the transition */
    }
}
```

Of course, you can instantiate the object using Spring:

```
<bean id="org.alfresco.behaviours.someObjectCreatePolicy" class="com.someco.alfresco.policy.SomeObjectCreatePolicy"
        init-method="init">
</bean>
```

Comment: I like the idea, I will work on it and see what I can do.

Comment: I update my question, i'm trying to change something, just to know how to begin to integrate applet in the the forms but nothing happens with the code changes... You know if it is the correct way or help me with the possible error in the code?

Comment: Where have you deployed your custom template?

Comment: I'm trying to change the original workflow only for testing. I already make a new workflow but, I'm testing if I can change the button "Accept" funcionallity. I have to make a new workflow mandatorilly to call a custom-acitiviti-transitions.ftl and this works?

Comment: I update the question with a link of my possible problem. And for that reason, maybe even I'll have to create changes in the new workflow.

Comment: You do not necessarily need a custom workflow if you are updating the alfresco template. Have you restarted alfresco or refreshed the share webscripts?

Comment: I will post more info later

Comment: Ok thanks. I already make changes on the original workflow edit-task page... My error was stupid. I'm trying now modify the button accept.

Comment: I tried modifying activiti-transitions.ftl and these changes take effect in alfresco. However when I make changes in the activiti-transitions.js do not show the changes. I tried to incorporate into ftl and still nothing.
The code is in the question.

Comment: If Alfresco is not running in debug mode, only the minimized versions of the javascript are read. Follow the configuration described in the following article to set Alfresco in debug mode: https://www.alfresco.com/blogs/kevinr/tag/javascript/

Comment: The minimized version works :) Thanks so much! Now don't jump to the task done but I will see tomorrow. The part of the applet will see tomorrow too and I give news. Thank you in advance what already helped.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102225/discussion-between-prvs-and-marco-altieri).

Comment: I made a question in the chat

Comment: i'm starting with this (Create behaviour). But if i shoud not try to submit, like you said, how to put "task done" @MarcoAltieri? any more hints?

Comment: In the code of the behaviour, you have to use the activiti API to close the task. Probably this question is not the best place to give details about it, but I will write an example.

Comment: You have reason. I will close this question and open another question with this specific question.

Answer (score 1):

We did a similar integration by opening the 3th party app (applet) in an iframe. 
The entry point was a custom document library action with custom client side java script to open the iframe and pass parameters to it, but I suppose if you want it to popup from a form button, you could provide a custom control for it.

The 3th pary app then communicates with alfresco using custom alfresco webscripts we wrote (for saving your pdf).

=>Alternatively If you have the applets java code, you might be able to move it to an alfresco java web script. That would simplify architecture significantly.

Comment: I already have a custom document library action that calls a page that contains the applet. 

The question is how could I provide a custom control for the form?

Comment: The alternative, is the same question, how can I put the web script on the form? 

Both cases you are speaking to integrate in a task from workflow right?

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35072740/integrate-applet-on-workflow-alfresco#comment57882117_35072740), it's doable, **BUT I DO NOT APPROVE THE WAY YOU ARE DOING THIS**

My understanding (from previous questions here on SO) is that you which to integrate document signing feature within your alfresco instance. And you have developed a doclib action that navigates to a special page with an applet to verify the user identity, sign the document and then upload a new (signed) version of it. Now, you need to integrate that same applet in a workflow in order to give users the possibility of asking other users to digitally sign documents (or something like that ..).

**Again, I would suggest you migrate your code from the applet to a service task (server side) as it would have more compatibility and more security** (FYI: not all browsers still support NPAPI, afaik at least Chrome doesn't any more, and so they need configuration in order to be able to run your applet !)

That being said, I guess the way for you to do this is :

1. Get some inspiration from `/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/workflow/activiti-transitions.ftl` and create your own `sign-transition.ftl` FTL in which you add html and js code for your applet just the same way you did in that page of yours.
2. Remember to fetch document noderef from the workflow package items (Remember, last time you got that information from a get param on your page url)
3. Once you had successfully uploaded the document on your repo (after signing it with your applet), your JS callback should invoke the same logic as when you press the transition button (make an Xhr to the form processor webscript with `task` as itemKind and `<taskId>` as itemId ....)

Comment: Where can I read in more detail about it? I am struggling to understand what really is this "activiti-transactions.ftl" page on alfresco, I have to put on the "sign-transactions.ftl" (it is my page that I have already created?) and how to call in the specific workflow . I want to show the applet on the form (edit-task) (probably) where it accepts the task as well. It must be after the workflow is created, i.e., on the task of each user. This page is this? But how to integrate? I am not able to understand the sequence of things to accomplish the goal.

Comment: `activiti-transactions.ftl` is the control for the button list at the end of your task-edit page, `sign-transactions.ftl` is the form control you need to create for that particular task to replace the OOTB (Out Of The Box) button with one other, similar to the button from the extra page you created. As for the rest of your comment, I am sorry I can not understand it!

Comment: if I understand, then my button of the page that contains the applet will be the "accept" button of the task-edit page right? And when I press the button "accept", I will redirect to the page that contains the applet and when I had successfully uploaded the document on my repo, I invoke the action of the original button "accept" right?

Comment: **YOU SHOULD NOT MODIFY THE OOTB ADHOC REVIEW WORKFLOW**, You should create your own workflow, check [this](http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/workflow/tutorial/tutorial.html) to learn how to create workflows. You shouldn't be redirecting to the applet page, you should include your applet in the `sign-transactions.ftl`template along with the necessary JS

Comment: I already create my own workflow. So, the sign-transitions.ftl template control the accept and the reject button right?  About this i dont find information. And on the New button, he calls the Applet and Update the document and makes the same logic as when I press the accept button?  Where I find the "code" of the button? The "accept" action code ?

Comment: First, sorry for doing a copy/paste of what you wrote ! It's `activiti-transitions.ftl` not `activiti-transactions`! And you will fin [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12977225/how-to-pass-workflow-propert-in-control-parm-to-ftl-file-in-alfresco) a sample cutomization of it.

Comment: Thanks. I'll see what I can do with that source.

Comment: I've done all the steps you said in the question, less 3). I lack only one thing ... When I update the document(already done), you say: "your JS callback shouldnt invoke the same logic the When You press the button transition (make an XHR to the form processor webscript with the task itemKind and the itemId ....) " and I don't understand how can I invoke this, to works well.